# Еще о шитье и швали

Tags: этимология

Почитал ответы на свой вопрос о слове "ошиваться" — всем огромное спасибо. Но тут же возник еще один вопрос: там написано, что "шваль" — это портной. Интересно тогда, откуда взялось в русском языке ругательство "шваль": от слова "портной" или от французского слова "cheval" — лошадь?
Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Шваль* - шьющий что-либо, швец;
*швальный* - относящийся к шитью;
*швальня* - комната, где шьют портные... (Словарь 1847).
Слова, всем известные в те далекие от нас времена. Но уже как бы немного устаревшие, вместо них появились другие, новые. А *шваль* приобретает вот такой негативный смысл :

> П.П. Вяземский. Письма и записки Оммер де Гелль (1845)
> **Эта шваль** обязана являться раз в день в контору и получать свою порцию.

Начинает брать сомнение : Вяземский, пишущий что-то там во французском стиле, не берет ли значение *cheval* - грубиян, "нехороший человек"? С другой стороны, портные и сапожники той замечательной эпохи позиционировались в российском просвещенном сознании как заслуженные пьяницы и дебоширы, отъявленные вымогатели, последние из последних.  Может быть, мы имеем дело со смешением смыслов, контаминацией. *Шваль* - низкого звания человек, простой работяга, подлый, необразованный, неумытая харя и тд. Позже появилось слово *шушваль* с тем же смыслом.

> Н. С. Лесков. Воительница (1866)
> Тоже ведь, гляди ты, **шушваль этакая**, а без любви никак дышать не могла.
> А. П. Чехов. Последняя могиканша (1884-1885)
> Молодой человек, ― обратилась она ко мне, ― по-вашему, это хорошо, ежели благородный человек **со всякою шушвалью** компанию водит?
> (Нацкорпус)

Скорее всего, соединение русского с французским (шваль/cheval)

Comment: О портных-швалях много чего наговорили, добавлю про его *родного братца*))) Когда в кинотеатре (советском, давнишнем) во время сеанса рвалась пленка, обязательно звучало возмущенное : "**Сапожник!!**"

Answer (score 1):

Позволю себе смелость дать объяснение слову **ШВАЬ** в аспекте иврита . Вот ивритное слово ** שאול** . Рассмотрим его сначала по буквам , - *внимание ! иврит читать справа налево .* Буква **ש** - шин(син) , звук Ш и С . Буква **א** - алеф , не имеет звука . Буква **ו** - вав , звук В (но может озвучиваться и как У , типа как в англ. Вильям-Уильям , Уинстон-Винстон , Уотсон-Ватсон) . Буква **ל** - ламед , звук Л . Гласных букв в иврите вообще не существует ,  читатель самостоятельно подставляет гласные звуки . Теперь приступим к озвучиванию и переводу этого **שאול** . Тут два варианта чтения и перевода . 1-й вариант звучит как **ШАУЛЬ** и означает "*заимствованный , взятый на время*"  либо имя *Саул* (в/зав. царь Саул /иначе Савелий). 2-й вариант звучит как **ШЕОЛЬ** и означат "*ад , преисподня*" . Нетрудно сообразить , что  2-й перевод в смысловой связи соответствует слову **ШВАЛЬ** . Ну , а теперь отметим , что вышеприведенные два варианта чтения взяты мной из словаря современного ,- *реконструированного и унифицированного* , - иврита . А этот *новый* иврит не во всём совпадает с тем старым ивритом , варьировавшемся по числу колен Израиля/12-ть/ ( также как и русские говоры ) и с теми вариантами иврита , на которых говорили различные локальные группы евреев во времена "великого изгнания" . Испанский сефард мог читать *так* , польский ашкеназ -  *этак* , а украинский маланец -  *разэтак* . Я просматривал материалы по диалектам иврита : там отмечаются разные подходы к чтению , а также буквено-звуковые перестановки согласный-гласный (ну , типа , как суровый-суворый , электричество-лепестричество /детск.жарг./ , инвалид-невалид /у Достоевсого в "Записках из мёртвого дома"./ ) . Кроме того , далеко не все евреи владели ивритом , как 1-м , т.е. родным , языком , что запросто  могло приводить к искажениям при прочтении слов из Торы или Талмуда . Тоже самое можно сказать и о некоторых самодеятельных грамотеях из числа церковных батюшек или монахов , взявшихся изучать язык Господа не по академическим учебникам (коих , вообще , могло не быть , или были в дефиците) , а без оных . Так что , суммировав вышеизложенное можно утверждать , что слово ШВАЛЬ суть диалектное или искажённое прочтение ивритного **שאול** - **ШЕОЛЬ**-**ШАУЛЬ** в значении "**АД** , **ПРЕИСПОДНЯ**" . P.S. А , что касается слова ШУШВАЛЬ , то здесь возможна игра-соединение вариантов ШУАЛЬ-ШВАЛЬ , типа ,как Вася-Василёк .

Answer (score 0):

> там написано, что "шваль" — это портной.

А где это "там" такое написано?
У Фасмера? В данном случае есть большое сомнение в адекватности такой  идеи... Но даже если он прав, то уж вариант случайной омонимии никак ни Фасмером, ни кем еще не опровергается.

Шваль (что-то никчечное, конченное) явно от французского. За что так портного обзывать - непонятно.

Answer (score 0):

МНЕНИЕ ИЗ ИНТЕРНЕТА

Слово "шваль" в русском языке означает "отрепье", "негодные вещи", "никчемный человек" и имеет негативный оттенок. Однако "шваль" -это не что иное, как русская транскрипция франЦузского слова "cheval", т.е. "лошадь". Известное слово "шевалье", например, означает "всадник", "рыцарь на коне".
Это слово пришло в наш язык во времена вторжения войск Наполеона. Уже по окончании войны на территории России оставалось много французов, и русские крестьяне не могли в полной мере обеспечить продуктами бывших оккупантов (в виде гуманитарной помощи, конечно). Французским солдатам приходилось есть даже павшую конину, даже ту, которая начинала проглядывать из-под снега и которая зачастую "дурно пахла". По одной версии, словом "шваль" презрительно окрестили "жалких французиков", по другой-все, что вызывало чувство брезгливости (в данном случае, останки павших лошадей). По этой причине слово "шваль" употребляется в русском языке в случае, когда необходимо высказать пренебрежительное, презрительное отношение к чему-либо.

Answer (score 0):

Шваль (  портной  ),  шваль  (  лошадь,  кобыла,  скотина ) из  француского  cheval  - это  обычные  омонимы.  Если  слово  шваль  вошло  в  русский  язык  после  1812  года,  как  и  шерамыжник,  то  по  отношению  к  шваль - портной  оно  более  позднее.  Хотя  я  этого  слова  в  текстах  не  припомню,  знаю  только  слово  швальня,  в  словосочетании - "полковая  швальня".  На  ругательный  смысл  слова  шваль  могло  повлиять  и  значение  корня  -вал-,  например  в  словах  валять,  свалка  и  т.п.

Comment: А  у  слова  "шушваль"  могло  быть  и  другое  происхождение.